# how to extract an id from a javascript in jmeter?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, nsregularexpression

i have a problem with extracting an id from a request in javascript. Let me explain, although I have inserted as a post processor a regular expression extractor with the following regular expression: (? <= Store_id :) \ d, the extraction of the value does not happen. Strangely, however, when I use this expression in the view result tree search this seems to work, the search finds me exactly the value I need, could you tell me where am I wrong?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the value you want as a group with parenthesis:

```
store_id:(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are case-sensitive by default in JS. Try this:

```
(?<=store_id:)\d+
```

I replaced `\d` with `\d+` because probably the ID may have more than one digit. If that's not the case, you can use `\d`.

Comment: thank you, I tried but unfortunately the problem persists

Comment: It seems to work: https://regex101.com/r/TJU5uu/1 Are you sure this is a problem with the regular expression?

Comment: I know, but when the scripts are run the value is not found.
it returns me the default value of the regular expression extractor.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the JavaScript code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
{store_id\s*:\s*(\d+)
```

[image]

where:

- `\s*` - optional number of whitespaces
- `\d+` - any number of digits
- `()` - grouping

See [Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) user manual chapter for more details

If you have problems when it comes to coming up with a proper regular expression alternatively you can go for the Boundary Extractor which basically extracts everything between left and right boundaries, it consumes less resources and works faster. More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

[image]